# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project spring-petclinic: There are test failures

Tags: spring

(I use windows 10, JDK 16, IntelliJ community version)

I cloned source from 'https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic'

And run

`cd spring-petclinic`

`.\mvnw package`

Then I see this error.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  41.192 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-19T23:43:14+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project spring-petclinic: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\ckh\spring\spring-petclinic\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin\java" -javaagent:C:\\Users\\looksun\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.5\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5-
runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\ckh\\spring\\spring-petclinic\\target\\jacoco.exec -jar C:\Users\looksun\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire6715219371849847653\surefirebooter6040109885809559579.jar C
:\Users\looksun\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire6715219371849847653 2021-03-19T23-43-11_017-jvmRun1 surefire17033458091815983550tmp surefire_014051529285808193773tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin\java" -javaagent:C:\\Users\\looksun\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.5\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5-
runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\ckh\\spring\\spring-petclinic\\target\\jacoco.exec -jar C:\Users\looksun\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire6715219371849847653\surefirebooter6040109885809559579.jar C
:\Users\looksun\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire6715219371849847653 2021-03-19T23-43-11_017-jvmRun1 surefire17033458091815983550tmp surefire_014051529285808193773tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:669)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:122)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
```

I have not only this results.

I didn't touch code before clone.

I have results follow:

```
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This time is my first time use to spring.
Please.... Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my Java version was very high.
Jajaco plugin was not support Java v16.

Let's go to download JDK 11.

I fixed.